# Kubeflow Kale installation on local Jupyter Hub notebook + Kubeflow Pipelines standalone installation on same local cluster. Is it possible?

Tags: kubernetes, jupyter-notebook, kubeflow-pipelines, kubeflow-kale

I am running a Kubernetes cluster on my local machine. In addition, I've managed to set up a Jupyter Hub environment with Kubernetes.

What I want to do is:

1. Install Kubeflow Kale on the Jupyter Notebook
2. Avoid the full installation of Kubeflow (I don't need everything from there)
3. Install the Kubeflow Pipelines as standalone (in the same cluster)
4. Deploy my ML models to KFP using Kale (directly from the notebook)

Is that possible? Most online guides (as also mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63778066/kubeflow-kale-how-to-integrate-kubeflow-kale-extension-to-run-pipelines-on-a)) are requiring the full Kubeflow deployment.

--

What I have already done/tried:

1. Followed the [official Jupyter Lab guide](https://zero-to-jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to set up my own Jupyter Hub
2. Followed the [official Kubeflow Kale installation guide](https://github.com/kubeflow-kale/kale#getting-started)
3. Found some [instructions](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/installation/overview/#kubeflow-pipelines-standalone) to install Kubeflow Pipelines as standalone